# Talend - NullPointer in BigDecimal.add()

Tags: nullpointerexception, bigdecimal, talend

I'm having an error on my Job when I do adding of BigDecimal  on my tMap.

this is my code.

```
Var.var1.add(Var.var2).add(Var.var3).add(Var.var4)
```

all of my variables are BigDecimal.

my error is 'NullPointerException'.

I already checked data on my Database and all have values. I also checked Nullable on my tMap.

Thank You.

Comment: It depends on how your vars are initialized.  It seems that var1 is null. Does your vars come from an outer join? Then, the vars can be null...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your job layout please?

Comment: I cant add an image yet. Nope. var is connected on my tOracleInput where is it from my database. Thank You

Comment: You can still host an image somewhere else and link to it. Someone else can edit the screenshot inline with your post easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because you are calling uninitialized variables.

Maybe you are writing this sentence inside the Var box in the tMap?

If not, are you able to output all the Var.varN BigDecimals independently without errors?